# Dynamic nav bar highlighting based on current selected tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails and I have a Bootstrap navbar. I need to make it so that depending on which navbar tab you click (Home, OOTD, Account), it will highlight it in some manner (like white text). I tried to dynamically get it to work using `active` and even a function which is supposed to toggle it, but it does not work.

My `application.html.erb`, which contains my navbar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Finalproj493</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" style="width: 100%; height: 5vw;">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/welcome/index">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item 1">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/ootd">OOTD</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item 2">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/account">Account</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>

    <br>
    <br>

    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was trying to use the `is_active()` function to dynamically toggle (the "Rails" way), but it was not working. The function is in my `application_helper.rb`, and I added the function call to it in my navbar (shown above):

```
module ApplicationHelper

    def is_active(action)       
        params[:action] == action ? "active" : nil        
    end
end
```

Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way, but can someone suggest a simple way that would incorporate `active` navbar styling in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `current_page?` to set the active class. You can create a method in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
def active_class(path)
 "active" if current_page?(path)
end
```

and you can use it like this:

```
<li class="<%= active_class(welcome_index_path) %>">
```

`current_page?` will return true and set the `active` class if the current request URI was generated by the `path` argument.

You can read more about `current_page?` [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F).